# Tensorflow: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'graph'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using `Keras == 1.1.0` and `tensorflow-gpu == 1.12.0`. 
The error is called after:

```
    input_layer = Input(shape=(2, ))
    layer = Dense(self._hidden[0], activation='relu')(input_layer)
```

and this is the Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Documents/PycharmProjects/DDPG-master-2/main.py", line 18, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:/Documents/PycharmProjects/DDPG-master-2/main.py", line 14, in main
    agent = Agent(state_size=world.state_size, action_size=world.action_size)
  File "D:\Documents\PycharmProjects\DDPG-master-2\ddpg.py", line 50, in __init__
    batch_size=batch_size, tau=tau)
  File "D:\Documents\PycharmProjects\DDPG-master-2\networks\actor.py", line 68, in __init__
    self._generate_model()
  File "D:\Documents\PycharmProjects\DDPG-master-2\networks\actor.py", line 132, in _generate_model
    layer = Dense(self._hidden[0], activation='relu')(input_layer)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 487, in __call__
    self.build(input_shapes[0])
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core.py", line 695, in build
    name='{}_W'.format(self.name))
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\initializations.py", line 59, in glorot_uniform
    return uniform(shape, s, name=name)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\initializations.py", line 32, in uniform
    return K.random_uniform_variable(shape, -scale, scale, name=name)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 282, in random_uniform_variable
    return variable(value, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 152, in variable
    if tf.get_default_graph() is get_session().graph:
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'graph'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I previously had tensorflow-gpu == 1.9 and uninstalled it and upgraded to 1.12, as I saw that it was a common solutions for similar problems. It did not work though.

EDIT (adding some relevant code related to the Traceback):

```
   agent = DDPG(state_size=world.state_size, action_size=world.action_size)

   self._actor = Actor(tensorflow_session=tensorflow_session,
                            state_size=state_size, action_size=action_size,
                            hidden_units=actor_hidden_units,
                            learning_rate=actor_learning_rate,
                            batch_size=batch_size, tau=tau)

       def _generate_model(self):
        """
        Generates the model based on the hyperparameters defined in the
        constructor.

        :return: at tuple containing references to the model, weights,
            and input later
        """
        input_layer = Input(shape=(self._state_size,))
        layer = Dense(self._hidden[0], activation='relu')(input_layer)
        layer = Dense(self._hidden[1], activation='relu')(layer)
        output_layer = Dense(self._action_size, activation='sigmoid')(layer)
        model = Model(input=input_layer, output=output_layer)
        return model, model.trainable_weights, input_layer
```

The code is related to three different classes.

Comment: Can you please put some relevant code? I guess it is related to imported packages.

Comment: Hi Amir, as relevant code I guess you mean the parts related to the Traceback? I'll put that right now

Comment: I run the model it throws an exception. Changing  ```input``` & ```output``` in ```Model()``` to ```inputs``` & ```outputs``` fix the issue. The rest of the code is just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue. Here are the things I did to resolve it:

1. Make sure that there is no other files in my project named `tensorflow.py`
2. re-install tensorflow with `--no-cache-dir` argument `pip --no-cache-dir install tensorflow` and removed pip cache files.

   For linux: 
   `rm -rf ~/.cache/pip/*` 
   For windows, delete the files in this location: `%LocalAppData%\pip\Cache`

I hope this helps

Comment: Hi John, thanks, I tried but unfortunately it doesn't work. Since the last line of the  Traceback is this `lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py`, it might be keras instead of tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved the issue. 
1. Uninstall `keras` with `pip uninstall keras`
2. Check that no other versions were installed (for example through `conda`)
3. Delete the cache in `%LocalAppData%\pip\Cache`
4. Re-install `keras`